# Enthalpy Of Water vapour at room temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

I am wondering how to calculate the enthalpy of water vapour at room temperature with a reference state of 25 C 1 atm.

I understand that normally for water vapour above boiling point, one would normally integrate the liquid heat capacity from the reference state to normal boiling point and then integrate the gaseous heat capacity from normal boiling point to the temperature of the water vapour. In addition to adding the enthalpy of formation and the enthalpy of vaporisation. However, I am unsure what to do if the temperature of the water vapour is below the normal boiling point as the gas heat capacity (obtained via the Shomate equation from NIST) is not valid at temperatures below the normal boiling point of water.

(Working so far)

[image]

Comment: Can there be pure water vapour at 25 °C and atmospheric pressure?

Comment: As with the above question, perhaps you mean to calculate the enthalpy of water vapor that is in equilibrium with liquid water at room temperature.